# Adding base64 decoding layer before input layer in Tensorflow Graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, graph

I want to add a layer to decode a base64 string to a numpy array which is a JPEG image. This layer needs to be in front of my original first layer of the model. I want to add a decoding layer because of this way I can reduce the network traffic and the speed.

I consist of a *.pb file which i load into a graph by this I try to manipulate that graph with the graph_editor module of Tensorflow which i'm stuck at.

```
def decode(entry):
    extracted_image = tf.io.decode_jpeg(tf.io.decode_base64(entry))
    expanded = tf.expand_dims(extracted_image, axis=0)
    resized = tf.image.resize_images(expanded, size=[320, 320])
    squeezed = tf.squeeze(resized, axis=0)

    return squeezed

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print("load graph")
    with tf.gfile.FastGFile(GRAPH_PB_PATH, 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        sess.graph.as_default()
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
        graph_nodes = [n for n in graph_def.node]


        # Get Graph
        g = tf.get_default_graph()


        input_feat = tf.placeholder(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name="input_images_str")
        decoded_input = tf.map_fn(decode, input_feat, dtype=tf.float32)

        input_tensor = g.get_tensor_by_name("input_images:0")

        _conn = graph_editor.connect(decoded_input, input_tensor)

        print(_conn)
```

I also tried connecting the original input_tensor with the decoding layer in Tensorflow.

```
        input_tensor = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("input_images:0")


        input_feat = tf.placeholder(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name="input_images_str")
        decoded_input = tf.map_fn(decode, input_feat, dtype=tf.float32)

        input_tensor = tf.matmul(decoded_input, input_tensor)


        output_tensor = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("feature_fusion/concat_3:0")


        # Saving
        inputs = {
            "input_images_str": input_feat
        }
        outputs = {"feature_fusion/concat_3": output_tensor}
        tf.saved_model.simple_save(
            sess, './tf_model/1', inputs, outputs
        )
```

The last method gave this back when making a prediction with a base64 image.

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_images' with dtype float and shape [?,?,?,3]